# Stylizing Horizontal Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, center, centering

I'm creating a horizontal navigation bar and would like to stylize it so that a thin line will appear right above the bar (please see example).

[Nav Bar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6hM1.jpg)

As you can see there is a thin, gold line just above the red navigation bar. I would like to get a thin, black line just above my orange navigation bar.

[image: Current Nav Bar]

My code looks like this:
(CSS)

```
nav {width:100%;display:block;}
nav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background-color:#c0872e}
nav li {display:inline-block;background-color:#c0872e;}
nav a {line-height:35px; color:white; padding:0 30px; font-size:22px; font-family:WindsorDemi.fog Cn; background-color:#c0872e;}
nav a:hover {text-decoration:none}
```

(HTML)

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this desired effect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using a border:

```
nav ul {
    border-top: 2px solid #000; /* Added */
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#c0872e
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwj109qj/) to show you how it looks.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this (add border-top)

**CSS**

```
nav ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;padding:0;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#c0872e;
border-top: solid 1px #000; // Add this (adjust your needs)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to change your surrounding div to the nav element.

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Then just add a border-top to the nav css.

```
    nav {width:100%;display:block;border-top:4px solid #000;}
    nav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background-color:#c0872e}
    nav li {display:inline-block;background-color:#c0872e;}
    nav a {line-height:35px; color:white; padding:0 30px; font-size:22px; font-family:WindsorDemi.fog Cn; background-color:#c0872e;}
    nav a:hover {text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could add a border just to the top.